# Can I install Visual Studio 2005 on my machine over 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2005, installation

I want to install Visual Studio 2005 on my machine which already has Visual Studio 2010?
Please help me out.

Bharat

Comment: possible duplicate of [Running Visual Studio 2005, 2008, and 2010 on same system.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2564633/running-visual-studio-2005-2008-and-2010-on-same-system)

Answer (score 0):

It can easily be done -- My other laptop has VS 2005, 2008, and 2010 all on the same drive.  The two versions shouldn't interfere with each other.  Visual Studio even has a "version selector" that gets registered as the handler for project and solution files, and IIRC it should launch the correct version of VS for whatever project you're in at the time.  But even if it doesn't, you can always right-click and "Open with...".