# visual studio 2010 and visual studio 6

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++-6

i have visual studio 2010 installed on windows 7 machine and now i want to install visual studio 6 on same.

Does it harm my visual studio 2010 or is there any way out for the same.????

Thanks in advance

Comment: i use both at the same time.You can too.

Comment: You'll lose some file associations.  Double-clicking, say, a .cpp file in Explorer will now open VS6 instead of VS2010.  Fairly annoying but not fatal.  The last VS version that can run on Win7 without compatibility problems (you'll see the warning) is VS2005.  This affects debugging most of all, I think.  13 years is your unlucky number and two dog lives in software engineering.  Consider a virtual machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've run several flavors of Visual Studio simultaneously on the same box installed in the order they were released.  [MS talks about doing this here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms246609%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) and lists a few cautions/notes about doing so.  Haven't installed them out of order before though, and haven't run VS6 in years.

[Here's another SO discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2564633/running-visual-studio-2005-2008-and-2010-on-same-system) talking about multiple versions.

As an aside, opening solutions with the newer version can make it difficult, if not impossible, to open it again in the older version of Visual Studio.

That said, a colleague said he had considerable issues getting VS 6 to run on Win 7.

My suggestion, if possible, would be to build up a VM with XP on it and install VS 6 on that - certainly simplifies things considerably.  Just my two cents.

Answer (score 1):

It shoudn't be a problem,except for webmatrix. I know there is an issue with launching visual studio from Webmatrix if the last install is not the latest see http://forums.iis.net/t/1176503.aspx for more details.