# Will running 3 versions of Visual studio on the same machine cause too much memory consumption?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2013

My system currently has Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition, Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate Edition installed. I'm thinking of installing Visual Studio 2013 Professional Edition. I referred to [***this link***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2564633/running-visual-studio-2005-2008-and-2010-on-same-system) which seemed to be a duplicate of my question. But there is no discussion there about memory consumptions.

My question is **will running 3 versions of VS on the same machine cause too much of memory consumption**? I'm having **8 GB** of RAM and an **i5 processor**.

I just want to be sure before I install. Any suggestions or answers will be welcome.

Thank you. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can have as many versions installed as you want without impact (other than disk space). On my previous machine (i5 proc and 8 gigs of RAM) I had VS2005, VS2008, VS2010 and VS2012 and I didn't notice an increase in memory consumption of individual instances.

Of course, if you run multiple instances at the same time memory consumption will rise, but that is still true if you run multiple instances of the same version of Visual studio. I regularly run two or three instances with fairly complicated solutions (20-50 projects) at the same time on 8 gigs of ram without slowdowns or issues.

Comment: Even ten instances should be fine. Currently, seven are running on my computer and require less then 2 GB overall (they share a lot as it seems).

Comment: I never had a need for seven instances :) But I think that it mostly depends on the size of the projects you are running etc. Also Resharper doesn't help with memory consumption

Comment: Thanks for the information :) I'll go ahead with the installation.

Comment: Not so much the size of the project, but the kind of documents that are open (using fancy designers).